# PIN request at each login after update to Maverick

Tags: 10.10, wireless, 3g

I have a netbook with included 3G mobile broadband card (Huawei E620). I have configured the broadband network connection in the Network Manager and it works perfectly.

However since Maverick upgrade, a window appears just after login I asking for the *SIMcard* PIN. This happens every time I log in and did not happen with Lucid. Note that the PIN is stored in the configuration of the mobile broadband connection and Lucid was satisfied with that.

Is there a way to prevent this request or, at least, to have the system rember the PIN and stop ansking for it?

If it may be useful, the broadband network connection is configured as not being available for other users. Also, I would like to keep the *SIMcard* asking for the PIN; only I do not want to insert it manually at login.

Comment: Have you ever tried to edit connections and then delete the above mentioned connection?

Comment: I managed to solve in a subobtimal way. I moved the card to a phone and disabled the PIN request, then moved back the card to my PC. This is not as secure as I would like, but it removes the annoying problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is a [known bug in the network-manager package](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/network-manager/+bug/704123) and was fixed in Version 0.9.2. The patch is not yet (December 2011) integrated in the mainline repositories.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if this will work or not but try adding the word "auto" in front of the name of your 3G network. I had a similar problem with my WPA wireless connection on autoconnect. Changing my network name, "Vidnet", to "auto Vidnet" fixed the issue with me.