# Since I upgraded to trusty, my mobile broadband card always asks for PIN

Tags: 14.04, password, mobile-broadband

I'm running Ubuntu on my Thinkpad x230 equipped with a mobile broadband card:

```
Bus 003 Device 025: ID 0bdb:1926 Ericsson Business Mobile Networks BV
```

This used to work seamlessly in Ubuntu 13.10 (and previous ones). After upgrading to Trusty, upon login, after resume I always get a dialog asking for the PIN of the SIM card. Marking "remember PIN" while answering doesn't help - the same dialog appears again upon next login or resume.

Any hints how to get rid of that dialog and remember the PIN? I'm aware that I can switch off PIN usage on the SIM itself, but I'd prefer a solution where the PIN is remembered.

## Addendum based on comments below

I have a broandband connection configured containing the PIN as well. The connection works perfectly fine.
The issue is that the PIN dialog pops up upon login and resume even if WWAN connection is not activated. Default connection is ethernet or Wifi. 
As a side information: I'm using [TLP](http://linrunner.de/en/tlp/docs/tlp-linux-advanced-power-management.html) - but I doubt that this is related to the issue.

The requested screenshot:
[image]

Comment: Sounds like `Passwords & Keys` app should store this info. - Can you check, if it's there?

Comment: No, it's not there. And I cannot see a way to add the PIN of my SIM card to that one.

Comment: mhmm. Maybe it's related to this: http://askubuntu.com/questions/19422/pin-request-at-each-login-after-update-to-maverick or this: http://askubuntu.com/questions/166680/gsm-sim-card-pin-code-recovery Can you try to open NetworkManager to find if you can enter your PIN in there and post a screenshot?

Comment: see my edits in the original question.

Comment: Have the same issue on my T430 after upgrade. Quite annoying. Have you tried to put the SIM in a phone and disable the PIN code and see if that helps? Probably not a great solution security wise, but it might be a functional workaround.

Comment: Is this question related to this bug - https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/network-manager/+bug/704123 ? One of the solutions is to uncheck the option "All users can connect with this network" in connection settings.

Answer (score 2):

I had same problem once on my Lenovo ThinkPad x230 but in Release 12.04 LTS with TLP. I then did find a solution so I disabled the SIM pin code on the card, then it stopped asking again and again. I know that is not a proper solution but maybe a workaround.

Answer (score 0):

TLP has settings to do things like power off PCI express, USB, etc when the machine is locked or goes to sleep or whatever. I would play with those settings and set it up so that your mobile card doesn't do anything when you close the lid or log out or lock the desktop or put it to sleep.

If that doesn't work, find the location of the config file and check the permissions. Make sure your user can both read and write. You could also try running the T-Mobile Bearbeiten tool with sudo or as the root user ("sudo su -" then your regular user password).

Basically, you need to make sure nothing is turning off or resetting the device (TLP or some Ubuntu power settings) and also make sure that the config file responsible for saving the password can be read and written by the user you login with.

If this doesn't help, let me know and I'll setup a similar situation on my pc and see if I can recreate and fix it.